# Is it right to say "what do you prefer to go to work?"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I created this structure from its possible answers like:

*I prefer buses to go to work.* ➡ *what means of transportation do you prefer to go to work* ➡ *What do you prefer to go to work?*

> But on second thought the first sentence seems wrong to me and I should change it to these:
>
> A: What do you prefer to go by to go to work?
>
> B: What do you prefer for going to work?

I know for sure that B is right. Even if it is correct, Can I replace **for going to work** with **to go to work** to have:

> What do you prefer to go to work?

Comment: I think, there are two "to go"s in A. Is it a typo or?

Comment: I think your final sentence, at the very least, lacks a preposition 'with'. "What do you prefer to go . . . " doesn't make sense.

Comment: Neither sentence is meaningful? You might ask: *How do you prefer to go to work?* but even this isn't clear. What you are trying to ask - as you indicate -is: *What means of transport do you prefer to use to get to work?*

Comment: @M.A.R. It's for the time when the answer is: I prefer to go with buses.--- I mean in your sentence "go" is for the noun "buses". In my sentence go is not for the verb, but instead for "for going to"; as a result the answer be like: "I prefer buses ➡ to go to work"

Comment: @RonaldSole What if the answer is "I prefer buses". Then the question would be: "what do you prefer?" I mean can I add "to go to work " to the last and have "what do you prefer to go to work?"?

Comment: @Reza If you have already set out the options - bus, taxi, car etc - then the question is: *Which do you prefer.....* If you haven't explained the context, the question is simply puzzling.

Comment: @Cardinal No. The original sentence is: what do you prefer to go by for going to work?" I just changed "for going to work" to "to go to work".

Comment: You probably haven't noticed you've dropped a 'by'.

Comment: So, the result would be "what do you prefer to go by to go to work ?". Am I right?

Comment: @Reza - The original sentence, "I prefer buses to go to work" sounds non-fluent to me, and I think that's part of the problem.  I would have stated it as "I prefer to go to work **by bus**", and the corresponding question would be "**How** do you prefer to go to work?" since we're asking about a method of doing something.

Answer (score 2):

As a (near-)native speaker, I would say (in no specific order):

> How do you get to work?

...or, if you need to indicate preference:

> How do you like to get to work?

But this is a little bit more informal.

And if you really want to use "prefer," I would say:

> How do you prefer to get to work?

And then, just some other options:

> What do you take to get to work?
>
> What do you like to take to get to work?

...although to "go to work" is not wrong, it just sounds "less" natural to me.

Meanwhile, I would not use "by" in any of these instances.

Adding "by" creates (a little) bit of unnecessary confusion.

While grammatically, it may be fine, it's not really necessary.

See how the last example, "What do you like to take to get to work?" is already a bit of a mouthful?

> What do you think? Which do you prefer? :D.

Comment: What about my question? (What do you prefer to go to work?) Is this wrong?  Because I taught it to my students an now I feel a little uncomfortable.

Comment: It's not wrong, but I can say that it's probably not the way a native speaker would say it. We would be more inclined to use "how" in this case, not "what." And we would be more inclined to use "to get to work" instead of "to go to work."

Comment: You mean it's grammatically correct but not common in use. Thanks 